# Performance issues with groupby's last in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns and a little over one-hundred thousand elements.

```
In [43]: df.head(10)
Out[43]:
                    localtime                 ref
4  2014-04-02 12:00:00.273537  139058754703810577
5  2014-04-02 12:00:02.223501  139058754703810576
6  2014-04-02 12:00:03.518817  139058754703810576
7  2014-04-02 12:00:03.572082  139058754703810576
8  2014-04-02 12:00:03.572444  139058754703810576
9  2014-04-02 12:00:03.572571  139058754703810576
10 2014-04-02 12:00:03.573320  139058754703810576
11 2014-04-02 12:00:09.278517  139058754703810576
14 2014-04-02 12:00:20.942802  139058754703810577
15 2014-04-02 12:01:13.410607  139058754703810576

[10 rows x 2 columns]

In [44]: df.dtypes
Out[44]:
localtime    datetime64[ns]
ref                   int64
dtype: object

In [45]: len(df)
Out[45]: 111743

In [46]: g = df.groupby('ref')
```

If I request the last element from my group, the function just hangs!

```
In [47]: %timeit g.last()
```

I killed it after 6 minutes; `top` shows the CPU at 100% the entire time.

If I request the `localtime` column explicitly, this will at least return, though it still seems absurdly slow for how few elements there are.

```
In [48]: %timeit g['localtime'].last()
1 loops, best of 3: 4.6 s per loop
```

Is there something I'm missing? This is pandas 0.13.1.

---

This issue appears with the `datetime64` type. Suppose I read directly from a file:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('so.csv')

In [3]: df.dtypes
Out[3]:
localtime    object
ref           int64
dtype: object

In [4]: %timeit df.groupby('ref').last()
10 loops, best of 3: 28.1 ms per loop
```

The `object` type works just fine. However, all hell breaks loose if I cast my timestamp:

```
In [5]: df.localtime = pd.to_datetime(df.localtime)

In [6]: df.dtypes
Out[6]:
localtime    datetime64[ns]
ref                   int64
dtype: object

In [7]: %timeit df.groupby('ref').last()
```

The plot thickens.

---

Reproducing without a data file, using Jeff's suggestion:

```
In [70]: rng = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=20,freq='s')

In [71]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(timestamp = rng.take(np.random.randint(0,20,size=100000)), value = np.random.randint(0,100,size=100000)*1000000))

In [72]: %timeit df.groupby('value').last()
1 loops, best of 3: 332 ms per loop
```

However, if I change the range of random integers, then the problem occurs again!

```
In [73]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(timestamp = rng.take(np.random.randint(0,20,size=100000)), value = np.random.randint(0,100000,size=100000)*1000))

In [74]: %timeit df.groupby('value').last()
```

I simply increased the `high` parameter of the second `randint()`, which means that the `groupby()` will have a greater length. This reproduces my error without a data file.

Note that if I forgo `datetime64` types, then there is no problem:

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(timestamp = np.random.randint(0,20,size=100000), value = np.random.randint(0,100000,size=100000)*1000))

In [13]: %timeit df.groupby('value').last()
100 loops, best of 3: 14.4 ms per loop
```

So the culprit is in scaling `last()` on `datetime64`.

Comment: try ``g.tail(1)``; can you post your file? (and the read_csv you are using to read it in ) (or if in other format ok, just post code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Must be something odd going on....looks ok in 0.13.1 (and master). Post a link to your file and i'll take a look.

```
In [3]: rng = date_range('20130101',periods=20,freq='s')

In [4]: df = DataFrame(dict(timestamp = rng.take(np.random.randint(0,20,size=100000)), value = np.random.randint(0,100,size=100000)*1000000))

In [5]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
timestamp    100000 non-null datetime64[ns]
value        100000 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
In [6]: %timeit df.groupby('value')['timestamp'].last()
100 loops, best of 3: 9.07 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit df.groupby('value')['timestamp'].tail(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.3 ms per loop
```

Ok here's the explanation:

Using `np.random.randint(0,100,size=100000)` for value, creates 100 groups,
while `np.random.randint(0,100000,size=100000)` creates a lot more (in my example
63000) or so.

`.last` (in < 0.14) implicity does the last of the `non-nan` values. This na testing is not that cheap, so this has poor scaling performance (and is done in python space for each group).

`tail(1)` on the other hand (in < 0.14) does NOT check for this so perf is much better (and uses a cython routing to get the results).

In 0.14 these will be the same (and even if you do it like this: `nth(-1,dropna='any')` which will replicate what `last` is doing here, this is done in a way to have much better perf. (thanks @Andy Hayden).

Bottom line is to use `tail(1)` in < 0.14.

Comment: Hmm, I can get your results. And oddly, if I save my DataFrame to a file and read it back, then the performance is great. Unfortunately I can't post my raw data because it is proprietary market data. I'll investigate some more and post an update when I find something. Oh, and `tail(1)` returns just fine; it's just `last()` that has trouble.

Comment: New info: If I save my DF and read it back, the `localtime` column becomes an `object` type. Getting the `last()` is very fast. However, if I convert the `localtime` back to a `datetime64[ns]` (via `pd.to_datetime`), then `last()` becomes slow!

Comment: are you ``parse_dates=True`` on the read in? but then ``pd.to_datetime`` reads it ok? (are their ``NaT`` generated in the field? (e.g. unparseable entries)

Comment: I've updated my question with a few more steps to repeat the problem. The trouble also occurs if I pass `parse_dates=['localtime']`. There are no null datetimes.

Comment: I cannot replicate this (on master or 0.13.1)

Comment: are you on 32-bit? os?

Comment: @Jeff I can reproduce the error using your example, simply by upping the `high` parameter in the second `randint()`. See the updated question. I have 64-bit Linux, by the way.

Comment: @Jeff: Could you post a link to where in the code `last` does na testing?

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L129; and a related issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6732

Comment: nth(-1,dropna='any') is *slightly* different than last, since last is the last non-NaN in each column (which may not be on the same row).... I think? eeep.

Comment: I am still seeing pretty dramatic performance improvements in 2022 with pandas version 1.4.1